# Remove outliers for all columns with R

Tags: r

I'm using these functions to remove outliers:

```
calcul.mad <- function(x) {
mad <- median(abs(x-median(x, na.rm=TRUE))) 
mad}

uper.interval <- function(x,y) {
up.inter <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(y) 
up.inter}

lower.interval <- function(x,y) {
low.inter <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(y)
low.inter}

functionData <- function(x,h,l) {
out <- ifelse(x > h, h, ifelse(x < l, l, x))
out}
```

Currently, I'm processing each column of a dataframe individually. Is there neat solution to apply these function across all columns of dataframe?

```
med_data <- median(column1, na.rm=TRUE)
cal_mad <- calcul.mad(column1)
up_data <- uper.interval(med_data, cal_mad)
low_data <- lower.interval(med_data, cal_mad)
column_without_outliers <- data.frame(functionData(column1, up_data, low_data))
```

Sample dataframe:

```
data_f <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100,10,10), col2=rnorm(100,15,15), col3=rnorm(100,20,20))
```

Comment: Check out the "colwise" function in the plyr package; that might do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try `summarise_each` from `dplyr` and apply the `median` and `calcul.mad`.  Once we got that, we can calculate the `uper.interval` and `lower.interval` after reshaping the `Sum_f1`.  Then, apply the `function_Data` once we get all the values.

```
library(dplyr)
Sum_f1 <- summarise_each(data_f,funs(median, calcul.mad))

n <-  2*ncol(data_f)

dl <- reshape(Sum_f1, idvar='id', direction='long', sep="_", 
                      varying=split(seq(n), as.numeric(gl(n,n/2,n))))


up_data <- mapply(uper.interval, dl[,2], dl[,3])
low_data <- mapply(lower.interval, dl[,2], dl[,3])
data_f1 <- data_f
data_f1[] <- Map(functionData, data_f, up_data, low_data)
```

Comment: Error in calcul.mad(Id) : could not find function "calcul.mad"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` on a data frame.

The code below changes the trim from 5x to 2x, since it's very unlikely a normal distribution will have values that distant from the median.

```
data_f <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100,10,10), col2=rnorm(100,15,15), col3=rnorm(100,20,20))

calcul.mad <- function(x) {
mad <- median(abs(x-median(x, na.rm=TRUE))) 
mad}

uper.interval <- function(x,y) {
up.inter <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+2*(y) 
up.inter}

lower.interval <- function(x,y) {
low.inter <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-2*(y)
low.inter}

functionData <- function(x,h,l) {
out <- ifelse(x > h, h, ifelse(x < l, l, x))
out}


outlier.fun <- function(column1) {
  med_data <- median(column1, na.rm=TRUE)
  cal_mad <- calcul.mad(column1)
  up_data <- uper.interval(med_data, cal_mad)
  low_data <- lower.interval(med_data, cal_mad)
  column_without_outliers <- functionData(column1, up_data, low_data)

  return(column_without_outliers)
  }

data_f_noout <- apply(data_f, 2, outlier.fun)

summary(data_f)
summary(data_f_noout)
```

Comment: You can use `apply` instead of having to coerce back to `data.frame` when using `lapply`. Both are equally as fast: `apply(data_f, 2, outlier.fun)`

Comment: I did some benchmarking comparing the accepted `dplyr` approach and this base R approach out of curiosity. Interestingly, the `dplyr` approach was only 7-10% faster.

Comment: @treysp I used `dplyr` only for the `first` line.  Other codes are just `base R`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with something like following

```
data_f <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(100,10,10), col2=rnorm(100,15,15), col3=rnorm(100,20,20))

library(tidyverse)

rmOutlier <- function(x){
                        low <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)-5*(mad(x)) 
                       high <- median(x, na.rm=TRUE)+5*(mad(x))   
                       out <- if_else(x > high, NA,ifelse(x < low, low, x)) 
                       out }

data_f2 <- map_df(data_f, rmOutlier)
```

There is `mad` function available in stats package for `calcul.mad` function that you have created. You can always use your own.